# Find and Replace Logic

Tags: vba, excel

Hi I have a specific Excel Sheet with list of 100+ queries in a column. The Queries are of the format below:

```
Select MKT_ID,Sum(NRX) FROM $$CURRENT_QUARTER_TABLE WHERE DATAMONTH = $$CURRENT_QUARTER_DATAMONTH
```

The $$ variables are my parameters that i intend to replace on runtime. I have a mapping of these Variables to their actual values in a Separate sheet in Excel. Something like

```
VARIABLE|VALUE
$$CURRENT_QUARTER_TABLE|BS_Q3_SALES
$$CURRENT_QUARTER_DATAMONTH|201606
```

Now how should i do this find and replace in vba? 
This is what i am doing to achieve this:

```
Dim Rng As Range
Set Rng = Config_Params.Range("C5:Q17") 'Range of all the Variable to Value Mapping
cnt = 38

For Each cl In Rng
    'rng2.Replace what:= cl.Value, replacement:=
    ReplaceStr = Trim(Config_Params.Cells(cl.row, 2) & "_" & Config_Params.Cells(4, cl.Column))
    Debug.Print qry
    Debug.Print ReplaceStr
    Debug.Print cl
    tmp = Replace(CStr(qry), CStr(ReplaceStr), CStr(cl))
   cnt = cnt + 1
Next
```

The values of variable used is as follows

```
SEL  count(distinct customer_id) from $$IHC_CURR_RAW_DUMP where customer_id is  null and  cycl_time_id =$$IHC_PREV_CYCL_TIME
$$IHC_CURR_RAW_DUMP
IHC_EXCLUSION_LIST
```

***Is there anyother optimized method to achieve this? any other strategy that i may use.***
Any help will be greatly appreciated. please Point to any already existing solution. I could not find specific to my problem.

Comment: build the query using the vals, so `"Select A from " + strSheet`    where `strSheet="$$IHC_CURR_RAW_DUMP"`

Comment: Thanks for the input, however i do not understand completely. I am making a solution which will be used by a guy doing operations with less knowledge of excel so i am to automate the whole process as much as i can

Comment: rather than replace placeholders, build the string, so set strTable to be your table for example, then use to build a SQL statement